# FluentMigrator: Disable the setting of a specific character set for each column or use the server default settings

Tags: c#, mysql, docker, fluent-migrator

I have a docker container with a `mysql:8.0`. At the very first launch (creating the container and volume), I run initial sql scriprt for create database, in which Default collation: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and Default characterset: utf8mb4. I am trying to create a new table using migration:

```cs
[Migration(0)]
public class Migration20231122190000 : Migration
{
    public override void Down()
    {
        Delete.Table("users");
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("users")
            .WithColumn("Id").AsString(38).PrimaryKey()
            .WithColumn("Login").AsString(30).Unique()
            .WithColumn("Password").AsString(255)
            .WithColumn("CounteragentId").AsString(38).ForeignKey("Counteragent", "Id");

    }
}
```

But when running the migration `runner.MigrateUp();` I get the following error: Referencing column 'CounteragentId' and referenced column 'Id' in foreign key constraint 'FK_users_CounteragentId_counteragents_Id' are incompatible.

Experimentally, exporting a new `users` table created using migration, without a foreign key, I found out that FluentMigrator sets a characterset and collation for each column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `Id` varchar(38) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Login` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `CounteragentId` varchar(38) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_users_Login` (`Login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

`select @@character_set_server` gives me `utf8mb4`

I know that I can add `.AsCustom("varchar(255)")` in the migration code, but you know, it's not very convenient to use such a construction for each column.

What do I need to do so that FluentMigrator does not complement each column with the CHARACTER SET and COLLATE construction, but uses the default server settings, for example `CounteragentId varchar(38) NOT NULL` or `CounteragentId varchar(38) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL`?